# C++ Pure virtual function not detected in subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, g++, pure-virtual

I have the following class structure:

```
class MyBase
{
   public:
      virtual ExportData exportData() = 0;
      virtual bool exportData(QString filepath)
      {
         ExportData data = exportData();
         data.save(filepath);
      }
};

class MyClass : public MyBase
{
   public:
      virtual ExportData exportData(){//some implementation}
};

class MySubClass : public MyClass
{
   public:
      virtual ExportData exportData(){//some implementation}
};
```

Then I export the data as follows:

```
MySubClass *sub = new MySubClass();
sub->exportData("/home/me/export.xml");
```

When trying to compile with g++, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MySubClass::exportData(QString)’
note: candidate is: virtual ExportData MySubClass::exportData()
note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

I don't see something I did wrong, why is this happening?

Comment: Those two functions do quite different things.  One exports data to a file, the other generates data to be exported.  Give them different and more descriptive names?  (And, if performance and responsiveness means anything, file io should be asynchronos -- which means io functions should be at the least name-typed, and maybe even expose async primitives: a very key way that these functions are not overrides of each other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your first virtual function hides your second function, you should do this in your subclass:

```
using MyBase::exportData;
```

Making this function explicitly visible to your subclass.

[Live Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2ehcbi%2419)

Comment: But the 2 functions have different parameters, so as far as I can remember the compiler will see them as two distinct functions. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @goocreations yes it will see them, but seeing you're deriving from your Base twice, and you're only then implementing one of your overloads, you're **hiding** the other, you need to bring it in scope with the `using`  statement, to let the compiler know that the other function also exists.

Comment: So I did that and get the following error: error: ‘virtual bool MyBase::exportData(QString)’ is inaccessible

Comment: @goocreations look at the example I posted.

Comment: Isn't there a better way? Have 8 subclasses at the moment, and I have to add it to every class.

Comment: I think if you have 8 subclasses you have a *design problem* more then anything else. That's overdoing the inheritance.  You should reconsider your design options

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25943/discussion-between-goocreations-and-tony-the-lion)

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `virtual ExportData exportData()` in `MySubClass`, you're hiding `virtual bool exportData(QString filepath)`. You need to bring it to scope with a `using` declaration:

```
class MySubClass : public MyClass
{
   public:
      using MyBase::exportData;
      virtual ExportData exportData(){//some implementation}
};
```